# Syntax error at line 53'end of file in the program below to write script to locate executable file

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh

FINDALL=false

if [ -a "$1" ]
 FINDALL=true
 shift
    for arg
                do
               if [ -f $file" ]
                  if [ ! -d "$file" -a -x "$file" ]
                        then
                        echo $file
                  else
                        echo $file is NOT FOUND
                  fi
               else
                 FOUND=false
               case $PATH in
               :*)
                 PATH=".:$PATH"
               ;;
               *::*)
                PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e 's/::/:.:/g'`
               ;;
               *:)
               PATH="$PATH:."
               ;;
               esac
               IFS=$OLDIFS
               IFS=:
               set -- $PATH
               IFS=$OLDIFS
                 for $P in PATH
                    if [ ! "$P/$file" -a -x "$P/$file" ]
                         then
                           FOUND=TRUE
                            echo $P/$file
                         if  FINDALL=FALSE
                           break
                         fi
                     else
                       if [ "$FOUND" = false ]
                        then
                        echo $file is NOT FOUND
                       fi
                done
              fi
      done
fi
```

Comment: That is really more appropriate for a site such as www.shellcheck.net IMHO

Comment: a missing **then** after first if ? vim can usualy color syntax and pinpoint closing keyword that are unopened.

Answer (score 1):

You have a large amount of errors in your script. If you're using a text editor like `vim` it will help you with syntax highlighting. Also as recommended by @steeldriver there are [good websites to help debug these types of errors as well](http://www.shellcheck.net).